# Transaction failing but I'm unsure why

Tags: solidity, flash-loans, flashbots, arbitrage

I am attempting to create a test arbitrage bot on the Goerli testnet.

Here is my smart contract which should perform a swap from Uniswap to Sushiswap :

```
pragma solidity =0.6.6;

import './UniswapV2Library.sol';
import './interfaces/IUniswapV2Router02.sol';
import './interfaces/IUniswapV2Pair.sol';
import './interfaces/IERC20.sol';

contract FlashLoaner {
  address immutable factory;
  uint constant deadline = 10 days;
  IUniswapV2Router02 immutable sushiRouter;

  constructor(address _factory, address _uniRouter, address _sushiRouter) public {
    factory = _factory;  
    sushiRouter = IUniswapV2Router02(_sushiRouter);
  }

  function uniswapV2Call(address _sender, uint _amount0, uint _amount1, bytes calldata _data) external {
      address[] memory path = new address[](2);
      uint amountToken = _amount0 == 0 ? _amount1 : _amount0;
      
      address token0 = IUniswapV2Pair(msg.sender).token0();
      address token1 = IUniswapV2Pair(msg.sender).token1();

      require(msg.sender == UniswapV2Library.pairFor(factory, token0, token1), "Unauthorized"); 
      require(_amount0 == 0 || _amount1 == 0);

      path[0] = _amount0 == 0 ? token1 : token0;
      path[1] = _amount0 == 0 ? token0 : token1;

      IERC20 token = IERC20(_amount0 == 0 ? token1 : token0);
      
      token.approve(address(sushiRouter), amountToken);

      // no need for require() check, if amount required is not sent sushiRouter will revert
      uint amountRequired = UniswapV2Library.getAmountsIn(factory, amountToken, path)[0];
      uint amountReceived = sushiRouter.swapExactTokensForTokens(amountToken, amountRequired, path, msg.sender, deadline)[1];

    
      token.transfer(_sender, amountReceived - amountRequired);
    
  }
}
```

Here is a link to my transaction: https://goerli.etherscan.io/tx/0x6f79454ef2a525c0dc05291dddd830dddc8688663d89e7f0fba4249bcff808dc

I am finding profitable trades on the testnet but my transactions fail. I cant see why its failing, is there a way to debug this or can anyone see if I'm doing something wrong in my Soliditiy?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I trace the transaction it has 0 gas left on UniswapV2Pair.sol:185

"gas":{
"gas_left":0
"gas_used":0
"total_gas_used":1000000
}

You need to pay way more gas for the call.

You can trace the transaction on https://dashboard.tenderly.co/tx/goerli/0x6f79454ef2a525c0dc05291dddd830dddc8688663d89e7f0fba4249bcff808dc/debugger?trace=0.2